# Temporizador Windows 10 para apagar la PC

Tags: powershell

Quiero hacer un pequeño temporizador para mi pc que haga lo siguiente:

Debe de coger y guardar la hora actual en una variable y si, por ejemplo

- La hora está entre las 00:00:00 y las 02:00:00 que se apague el equipo en 2 horas

  ```
  shutdown -s -t 7200
  ```
- Y si es mas de las 02:00:00, que el shutdown sea en 1 hora en lugar de dos.

Sé que tengo que usar `IF` y un `AND` en la primera condición, y el shutdown claro está, pero no sé en .bat cómo hacerlo la verdad.

También he leído que quizá sea más fácil con PowerShell. No lo sé la verdad.

Comment: Hola @Javilpc. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! Estás diciendo que PowerShell es una alternativa. ¿También intentaste con otro lenguaje? ¿Te interesa escribir el código o simplemente cualquier utilidad de terceros te serviría?

Comment: Buenas @Mariano, me interesa conocer el código por el mero hecho de aprender la sintaxis ya que el algoritmo lo tengo claro de otros lenguajes que si manejo un poco mejor, entonces me vendría muy bien el código escrito

Answer (score 1):

Lo siguiente puede funcionar.  No lo he probado entre medianoche y las dos de la mañana ni entre mediodía y las dos de la tarde.

```
$ahora = get-date
if ($ahora.hour -lt 2) {$seg = 7200} else {$seg = 3600}
shutdown -s -t $seg
```

Hay formas más elegantes de lograr lo mismo. Este ejemplo sólo emplea lo más básico de powershell.  shutdown no es parte de powershell, sino que es accesible dentro de powershell.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
TITLE Apagar
MODE con: cols=50 lines=40
COLOR 02
:menu
echo                 iP@@@@@@@2     iOMBMBMBB@  5BMBMBB@B    
echo               5@B@B@@@B@B@BU  i@B@B@B@B@B B@B@B@B@@@   
echo             :B@B@@@SUuBB@B@Bv MB@B@M@@@Bi @B@@@B@B@,    
echo            .B@B@M      .B@B@B B@B@       kB@Bv           
echo            @@B@Z        7@@B@ MB@@,::ir: B@B@L,:ii:      
echo           r@B@B         r@B@@ B@B@B@@@Bq @B@B@B@B@1         
echo           E@@B@         @B@@2 @B@B@B@B@ LB@B@B@B@B       
echo           L@B@B2      .@@@B@ O@@B       B@B@:             
echo            B@B@B@7,,vM@B@B@ vB@BS      .@B@@           
echo             B@B@B@B@B@B@BO  @@B@,      EB@BM            
echo              r@B@B@B@B@F.  r@B@B       B@B@r             
echo                 ,;;:.      ..          ,  . 
echo.            tiempo de 2.horas = 7200
echo.              DIA %date%  HORA %time%
set /p tiempo=El tiempo de apagar :
if %tiempo% =="7200" goto end
if %time% ==""02:00:00,00"" goto end   
goto menu

:end
shutdown -s -t %tiempo% -c "La computadora se apagará automáticamente
"La computadora se apagará automáticamente
goto exit
```

*Copia en un bloc de notas y le cambias la extección por un .bat
**ESPERO QUE TE FUNCIONE***

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esto:

```
@echo off

set "now=%time: =0%"

if "%now%" GEQ "00:00:00,00" (

      if "%now%" LEQ "02:00:00,00" (

           shutdown.exe -s -t 7200

      )
)

if "%now%" GTR "02:00:00,00" (

      shutdown.exe -s -t 3600

)
```

¡Espero que te funcione!

Answer (score 0):

Me gustó mucho tu consulta, me pareció muy interesante así que me di a la tarea de investigar y probar, este fue el código que hice a partir de lo que encontré:

```
@echo off

SET HOUR=%time:~0,2%
IF "%hour:~0,1%" == " " SET HOUR=0%HOUR:~1,1%

SET MIN=%time:~3,2%
IF "%min:~0,1%" == " " SET MIN=0%MIN:~1,1%

SET SECS=%time:~6,2%
IF "%secs:~0,1%" == " " SET SECS=0%SECS:~1,1%

SET TIME_TO_SHOW=%HOUR%:%MIN%:%SECS%
SET TIME_TO_VALIDATE=%HOUR%%MIN%%SECS%

SET SECONDS_TO_SHUTDOWN=999999999999

IF %TIME_TO_VALIDATE% GEQ 000000 IF %TIME_TO_VALIDATE% LEQ 020000 SET SECONDS_TO_SHUTDOWN=7200

IF %TIME_TO_VALIDATE% GTR 020000 SET SECONDS_TO_SHUTDOWN=3600

ECHO La hora actual es: %TIME_TO_SHOW%, el computador se apagara en -T %SECONDS_TO_SHUTDOWN%

SHUTDOWN -s -t %SECONDS_TO_SHUTDOWN%

PAUSE > NUL
```

Es un simple archivo de texto plano guardado con la extensión `.bat`, lo probé y a mi me funcionó correctamente validando la hora y "seteando" correctamente el "argumento" `-t`, en los `scripts` `batchs` los operadores condicionales son los siguientes (para que entiendas como funciona el código anterior):

`EQU` - equal - igual que

`NEQ` - not equal - no igual - diferente de

`LSS` - less than - menos que

`LEQ` - less than or equal - menos o igual que

`GTR` - greater than - más que

`GEQ` - greater than or equal - más o igual que

Cabe decir también que los operadores `AND` y `OR` no existen pero puedes validar estos con un doble `if` (como el que aparece en el código)

Answer (score 0):

Muy buena pregunta, podrías utilizar el siguiente codigo en Powershell, lo podes ejecutar directamente en consola o guardarlo como un archivo con extensión "ps1". 
La primer linea guarda en variable la fecha y hora actual para luego hacer comparaciones.
De la segunda a la quinta linea, hace un IF-ELSE donde compara el horario actual con el rango que pedias. (00AM a 2AM) "gt" y "lt" son operadores the comparacion que significan "greater than" y "lower than" respectivamente.
Espero que te sirva.

```
$actual = (Get-Date) 
if ($actual -gt "00:00:00" -and $actual -lt "02:00:00") 
    {$tiempo =  "7200" } 
else 
    {$tiempo = "3600"}
shutdown -s -t $tiempo
```